# If file name is incorrect then move it to bad folder

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have this scenario where i need to check for file name in a folder where files are kept for migration.

If the file name do not match with name we suggest the client to give then move it to bad folder.
Also there could be multiple files in the same folder so i need to pick only files which are not matching the string i am looking for.

I have this piece which can tel me if file name is correct or not

```
if [ ! -f /data/cmts_map_*.csv ]; 
then
  echo "File not found"
fi
```

but now i got stuck like suppose there is folder data

```
    data]$cs_map_13672.csv
         dhcp_map_5485.csv
         link_map_875485.csv
```

So here in data folder i have 3 files out of which first file name is incorrect and rest of two are correct.
So the incorrect file should move to bad folder i am only able to identify and print a message for this but got stuck like how to pick that only first file to move.

Also i have thre blocks for each file to process for migration like this

```
FILE=`ls ./data/cmts_map_*.csv`
FILE_CMTS=$(basename $FILE)
mv ./data/$FILE_CMTS ./data/cmts_data.csv

FILE=`ls ./data/dhcp_map_*.csv`
FILE_DHCP=$(basename $FILE)
mv ./data/$FILE_DHCP ./data/dhcp_data.csv

FILE=`ls ./data/*_link_*.csv`
FILE_LINK=$(basename $FILE)
mv ./data/$FILE_LINK ./data/link_data.csv
```

So this was a little part of my original script where i am checking for file names and renaming them for ease.

I want to add

```
if [ ! -f /data/cmts_map_*.csv ]; 
then
  echo "File not found"
  mv ?
fi 
FILE=`ls ./data/cmts_map_*.csv`
FILE_CMTS=$(basename $FILE)
mv ./data/$FILE_CMTS ./data/cmts_data.csv
```

Because we are not sure the incorrect name could be anyting !

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a find :

```
find . -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*.csv' -exec mv -t ./badfolder/ {} \+
```

**Update :**

To move files matching one of the three patterns in a parent /badfolder/ dir and add each file a `.bad` extension :

```
find . -type f ! -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' ! -name 'cmts_map_*.csv' ! -name '*_link_*.csv' -exec mv '{}' ../badfolder/'{}'.bad \;
```

Comment: But again if i have three file in the folder then it will all the files in the bad folder which is not good !

Comment: The `find` applies to files. Only matching files will be moved.

Comment: Hey i have just run your command and it moves everything from that folder into badfolder :(

Comment: I am thinking that if somehow i can capture the incorrect file in a variable then we can move it to the badfolder !!!

Comment: It works for me for the `cmts_map_*.csv` pattern, but with Bash. Maybe some adjustement to do according to your shell.

Comment: find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv' I am planning to use this command for incorrect file name to store it in a vaiable then move it to bad folder

Comment: cd data
curr=`pwd`
echo $curr
bad_file=`find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv'`
BAD_FILE=$(basename $bad_file)
mv $BAD_FILE ../bad/$BAD_FILE.bad

cd ..

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ ! -f /data/cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv ]; 
then

cd data

curr=`pwd`
echo $curr

bad_file=`find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv'`
BAD_FILE_LINK=$(basename "$bad_file")

echo $BAD_FILE_LINK

echo "Bad File Found please check bad folder"

mv $BAD_FILE_LINK ../bad/$BAD_FILE_LINK.bad

fi

cd ..

if [ ! -f dhcp_map_*.csv ]; 
then

cd data

curr=`pwd`
echo $curr

bad_file=`find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv'`
BAD_FILE_DHCP=$(basename "$bad_file")

echo $BAD_FILE_DHCP

echo "Bad File Found please check bad folder"

mv $BAD_FILE_DHCP ../bad/$BAD_FILE_DHCP.bad

fi

cd ..

if [ ! -f cmts_map_*csv ]; 
then

cd data

curr=`pwd`
echo $curr

bad_file=`find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv'`
BAD_FILE_CMTS=$(basename "$bad_file")

echo $BAD_FILE_CMTS

echo "Bad File Found please check bad folder"

mv $BAD_FILE_CMTS ../bad/$BAD_FILE_CMTS.bad

fi

cd ..
```

this way i can move incorrect fime into bad folder but again i encounter a problem when i put all three files with incorrect name then it gives me error like ----

```
Bad File Found please check bad folder
mv: missing destination file operand after `../bad/.bad'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
/home/vmsow03qa/domains/vm/tools/topology_data_load/data
basename: extra operand `./cts_map_0309151623_1.csv'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

Anu guess it happens only when there are 3 incorrect files if there are only or one incorrect file then it works perfect !